# Regex match inside html tag

Tags: c#, regex

My html as below

```
 <body><table><tr><td> <h4><span><strong><span>This Text</span></strong></span></h4> </td> <td> <h4><span><strong>That Text<br></strong></span></h4> </td> <td> <h4><span><strong><span>Some Text</span></strong></span></h4> </td> <td><span><strong>0 505 253 56 13</strong></span></td></tr><table></body>
```

The following regex cleans all tags without **a|p|img**

```
 _QsHtml = Regex.Replace(_QsHtml, @"<\/?(?!a)(?!p)(?!img)\w*\b[^>]*>","", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I would like to apply ragex for only table row (td). I have tried following regex but not matched.

```
<\/?td(?!a)(?!p)(?!img)\w*\b[^>]*td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: regex may not be a good idea for parsing html: https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/1287916; using html specific parsers may be a more solid approach.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all tags except td or only td tags?

Comment: http://html-agility-pack.net

Comment: @smn.tino I would like replace with empty string unnecessary tags

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes I am using html agility for remove class but html agility not appropriate for replace string. It is using DOM structure

Comment: @smn.tino: You linked a wrong answer, see NikiC comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: td is actually a column. do you want to remove columns or a complete row with columns in it?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved problem with combine Html Agility full working codes as below

```
string _QsHtml =  @"<body><table><tr><td> <h4><span><strong><span>This Text</span></strong></span></h4> </td> <td> <h4><span><strong>That Text<br></strong></span></h4> </td> <td> <h4><span><strong><span>Some Text</span></strong></span></h4> </td> <td><span><strong>0 505 253 56 13</strong></span></td></tr><table></body>";

var _HtmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
_HtmlDocument.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
_HtmlDocument.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
_HtmlDocument.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
_HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(_QsHtml);

 var FindTableRows = _HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td");

 if (FindTableRows != null)
 {
     foreach (var TableRow in FindTableRows.ToList())
     {
         string _InnerHtml = TableRow.InnerHtml;

        _InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(_InnerHtml,
                               @"<\/?(?!a)(?!br)(?!img)\w*\b[^>]*>",
                               "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        TableRow.InnerHtml = _InnerHtml;

     }
 }
```